# Could I probably output the name of a JSON object?

Tags: json

Imagine I set up a JSON like this:

```
"A": {
    "appointment": {
        "201405091210": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
}
"B": {
    "appointment": {
        "201405091211": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
}
"C": {
    "appointment": {
        "201405091212": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
}
```

So say now I like to output the "name" of the first object in each object, meaning:

201405091210
201405091212
201405091212

Can I do that?

I tried:

```
  $.each(data, function (index, data) {
      console.log(data.appointment[1]);
  })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "probably output"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time your code is running, you don't have JSON, you have a JavaScript object.

> So say now I like to output the "name" of the first object in each object, meaning:

If your data is really as shown (there's only one property within the `appointment` object), then you can use `Object.keys()` and take the first (only) entry to get the name of the only property in the `appointment` object:

```
$.each(data, function (index, entry) {
    console.log(Object.keys(entry.appointment)[0]);
});
```

Another approach is to use `for-in` and grab the first "own" property:

```
$.each(data, function (index, entry) {
    var name;
    for (name in entry.appointment) {
        if (entry.appointment.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            console.log(name);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

If there may be more than one property in the `appointment` object, you can't reliably get the "first" property name.. The properties in JavaScript objects have no defined order. You'd have to look at all of the properties and determine (perhaps by checking for ones that match a particular pattern) which is the one you want.

---

Side note: I changed your `data` argument in the `each` iterator function to `entry` to avoid being confusing. Having `data` outside the iterator refer to the whole thing but `data` *inside* the iterator referring to just one of the entries is just asking for trouble.